# How to ensure that gnus only check for new messages in my subscribed groups

Tags: gnus

Gnus scans thousands of groups on the news server upon startup.  How do I restrict it to only my subscribed groups?

**Edit**: This happens despite having set gnus-default-subscribed-newsgroups to true in my .gnus.el file.  I have also set gnus-check-new-newsgroups to nil to no avail. I am using Emacs 27.1.

Comment: Have you looked through [`(info "(gnus) New Groups")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/New-Groups.html) and its subnodes?

Comment: Why don't you submit a bug report that provides more details of your setup/server with `M-x gnus-bug RET`?

Comment: `gnus-default-subscribed-newsgroups` should not have any effect. Because this variable is not documented anywhere.

Comment: In the group buffer, type "A u" to see your list of subscribed groups. It could be that you have subscribed to thousands without realising it?

Answer (score 2):

Gnus scans only subscribed groups on startup. To find new groups you will have to explicitly invoke `gnus-group-find-new-groups` which has a keybinding `F` in the Group-buffer.

Comment: This is not happening in my case.  Upon startup, gnus scans all the thousands of newsgroups on the server.

Comment: Are you sure those groups are not subscribed. Because the groups which have no new messages also doesn't appear in the group buffer but they are scanned.

Comment: Have you played with `Group Levels` recently? Read about it in Gnus Manual.